# Python / Gtk - embedding into X window ID

Tags: python, qt, gtk, embedding

I wrote a program using Qt 4.8, which used the QX11Embed mechanism to embed a useful little python/gtk widget.
I forked the widget, got its winID and then embedded it in a Qt container widget. This worked well

Then I had to change to Qt5 and the whole QX11Embed code has been dropped:(

Apps that take a winID as a commandline arg and embed into it, like mplayer or xterm, still work with Qt5.  You just create a container, pass its winID to the app, but not the other way around.

I am not a python programmmer, but even so I am considering changing the widget itself so that it embeds itself into a given winID, but I cannot find any examples or docs.
Every search that mentions embedding goes to the plug/socket mechanism for embedding INTO gtk, nothing the other way around.

How should I go about it, is it even possible, any links etc

Thanks

Comment: [QWindow, QWidget, Qt5, X11Embedding](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/33363).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, but as per others comments, it just doesn't work with 'foreign' windows. I just get a separate window and a black rectangle where the container widget is in the app.  I have been through Qt5 'solutions' ad nauseum, which is why I want to try rewriting the python app to TAKE a winID and embed into it.